Trying to develop my own DevContainer but never ask for templateOptions
I'm trying to develop my own DevContainer and I have a few doubts:

the dev container I developed works good when I open it locally
is correct to say that if opened locally you will not be asked for devcontainer-template.json options?
the ask for templateOptions worked pretty well until a few weeks ago on some containers on devcontainer-template-collection.json (offical VSCode containers) but now, also containers asked for options on initialization in the past, don't ask anymore options for me.

Is this a problem I got or is it really broken for everyone? I tried javascript-node-mongo that have imageVariant option and it's not working for me, it doesn't ask for a value (https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/blob/main/src/javascript-node-mongo/devcontainer-template.json).
Thanks!
Having a prompt with the options.
